# ServiceMix config change for a bundle in scripting mode using `client` binary

Tags: bash, client, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I have a ServiceMix 5.1.4 instance (localhost) and I want to script some property change with the provided client (smx_home/bin/client).

If I test manually my commands in the smx console (without using `client`)

```
config:edit org.myspace.test.mybundle
config:propset propertyOne false
config:propset propertyTwo true
config:update
```

... it works great.

Now I want to execute these command from a bash, then I wrote a simple bash like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

smxcli='/opt/mysmxdir/bin/client'

$smxcli -h localhost -a 8101 -u smx -p smx config:edit org.myspace.test.mybundle
$smxcli -h localhost -a 8101 -u smx -p smx config:propset propertyOne false
$smxcli -h localhost -a 8101 -u smx -p smx config:propset propertyTwo true
$smxcli -h localhost -a 8101 -u smx -p smx config:update
```

or if I tried with the client itself in the command line, it fails on the second line as it does not look to keep track of the first `edit` command.

```
No configuration is being edited--run the edit command first
```

I tried to provide the commands like a list:

```
./client -h localhost -a 8101 -u smx -p smx  "config:edit org.myspace.test.mybundle" "config:propset propertyOne true" "config:propset propertyTwo false" "config:update"
```

and with the option -b (batch)

```
./client -h localhost -a 8101 -u smx -p smx  -b "config:edit org.myspace.test.mybundle" "config:propset propertyOne true" "config:propset propertyTwo false" "config:update"
```

but it does not work.

I know I can use the option -f (writing all smx commands in one file and execute them with `client -f myfile.cmd`) but I am wondering if it is possible from a single bash script without extra file.

Comment: afaik this has been a known issue in Karaf which is fixed ... you'll need to wait till a servicemix based on Karaf 3.0.5 is released.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck if you can put a link on the Jira (if any) it would be nice. I checked also the servicemix / karaf documentation but did not find a good example which shows how to use the `-b` option of the client.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck In fact I found the solution to my problem by using the same notation as in `bash`. It seems there was no issue in my old verison finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the solution was very simple: like in unix/linux you can separate commands by a semicolon `;` in the same command string.

*Example:*

```
./client -h localhost -a 8101 -u smx -p smx  "config:edit org.myspace.test.mybundle; config:propset propertyOne true; config:propset propertyTwo false; config:update"
```

I found it is also possible to send all commands at once for several bundles. If I try to send two different command, for changing properties for two different bundles the second one is not working.

In that case the solution is to concatenate all the changes with only one command like this:

```
./client -h localhost -a 8101 -u smx -p smx  "config:edit org.myspace.test.bundle-1; config:propset propertyOne true; config:propset propertyTwo false; config:update; config:edit org.myspace.test.bundle-2; config:propset propertyX true; config:propset propertyY false; config:update"
```